# Verification of the explanation of white noise process

Tags: time-series, self-study

I conclude the other post from stack-exchange, and Wikipedia, I come up with the following explanation of white noise process. My question is simply **want to know whether my understanding is correct or not**

My explanation:

> if a_t is said to be a white noise process
>
> white noise process , can be viewed as combination of 2 part, "white noise"&"process" the first part use the physical properties of white noise to describe the statistical properties of the process. The latter part is to point out this sequence of no. is a process.
>
> Therefore the white noise process should have the following properties:
>
> 1.E(a_t)=0
>
> 2.var(a_t)=S^2
>
> 3.ACF of a_t =0